# Using a button in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to learn how to get a button (in my case, a 'Cancel' button) to direct me back to the previous page it was on. I've got a button on my previous page that directs me to this page, and i want this button to take me back to the previous page and discard anything i had written on the page. My button on my first page pushes the view to this page through a modal connection. I know it would make sense to just use the simple modal connection for the Cancel button to get back to my original page, but I was hoping for a more elegant way to do this. Creating a custom view is a good idea i'm sure but I don't really know what to do there so.. haha but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
#import "AddEventViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AddEventViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *addEventTitleBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation AddEventViewController

@synthesize textField1, textField2, textField3, myTextView;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField1.delegate = self;
    textField1.delegate = self;
    self.textField2.delegate = self;
    textField2.delegate = self;
    self.textField3.delegate = self;
    textField3.delegate = self;

    [myTextView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [myTextView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [myTextView.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
    [myTextView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [myTextView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.002f];
    [myTextView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0f];
    [myTextView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event
{
    if (textField1)
    {
        if ([textField1 canResignFirstResponder]) [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];

    if (textField2)
    {
        if ([textField2 canResignFirstResponder]) [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];

    if (textField3)
    {
        if ([textField3 canResignFirstResponder]) [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == textField1)
    {
        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == textField2)
    {
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == textField3)
    {
        [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)addCancelButton
{
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
}

-(void)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

@end
```

Fixed the issue!

Comment: plse provide more information, do you have navigation controller? how do you push the view etc..

Comment: Yes. I'm using a tabbed application. my 1st tab has a Navigation bar at the top. A bar button item in the top right directs me to this page. And on this page i have a navigation bar. I want the 'Cancel' button in the top left corner to direct me back to my original first tab view controller, and i want it so it discards everything i had done on the page when i click the cancel button. @SpaceDust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

```
- (void)addCancelButton{

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];


    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;

}



- (void)cancel:(id)sender{
    //If presented
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //If pushed
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```

Where the code in AddCancelButton can be moved to viewDidLoad or somewhere appropriate. And you might want to edit how the view is removed depending on how it was added (pushed, presented etc.)

Comment: `style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction`? Are you sure? Please don't post wrong answers...

Comment: Ooops, you're absolutely right.

Comment: I put that code into my .m file and it didn't work... So i tried putting the (void)addCancelButton part into my viewDidLoad part of my code, and that didn't work either...

Comment: wait so what do i do? @johan

Comment: If you pushed the view controller you should use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; Will update the answer.

Comment: my connection is a modal.. not a push.. is that bad? should i change it? @johan

Comment: It's nothing bad with a modal. Just another behavior :)

Comment: Ya what is the difference? cause i have no idea haha @johan

Comment: So do you know how to do this button thing? @johan

Comment: You so it as it's done in my sample. Something else is broken if it doesn't work. Really hard to guess. Sorry :S

Comment: I edited my question. Look at my code.. What is the issue? @johan

Comment: I'm confused on how i would do this code differently since my connection is a modal? do you know @johan ?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this to work with a modal connection? and i tried changing it to a push connection, but then the app crashes... HELP ME @johan

Comment: addCancelButton never called?

Comment: I figured it out.. I didn't even need any code.. i just used another modal connection from the cancel button to the first view controller... no code was necessary.. but for the animation do you know how to do the transition 'Cover Vertical' From top to bottom instead from bottom to top? @johan

Comment: Chose push (or whats it's called) instead of modal in the segue

Comment: I changed the connection between the cancel button and the first view controller to a push, but now the app crashes when i press the cancel button.. any other way? @johan

Comment: @johan i figured it out! thanks again for the help!